# How can I replace the perished seal around my rear lights on my BMW E46?

Tags: bmw, seal, trunk

I realised today that the seal around the rear lights, where the drainage around the trunk runs over, has perished on both sides of my car. Right side is worse with a substantial gap missing. I definitely don't want to chance rust or failed electronics so I need to fix it.

[image: perished seal around rear tail light]

So how can I fix it? I'm hoping it's just a new seal rather than the whole lighting fixture. It's a BMW E46 330Ci 2002 with the sport package. Pre-facelift I believe.

Comment: What year is the vehicle? And what model/trim E46?

Comment: @JasonC Ah yes, forgot that detail. Added, it's a 330Ci 2002 w/ sport package.

Comment: I don't have experience fixing things stuck on with adhesives (that's why I deleted my answer), but yes, you can fix this. The part is available separately, it's #9 in the diagram [here](http://parts.bmwofsouthatlanta.com/showAssembly.aspx?ukey_assembly=258309&ukey_product=1410563). The actual part is [this one if you don't have the convertible](http://parts.bmwofsouthatlanta.com/products/BMW-3-Series-E21-E30-E36-E46-E90-E91-E92-E93/2002/330Ci/Covering--right/1437660/63216933018.html) (*might* be a different p/n for the 330ci convertible); it cost roughly 15 USD. So you're in luck.

Comment: @JasonC nice find. Mine is the coupe, so could be a win, but going to need to look more carefully at that. Can't see exactly what the part is just yet.

Comment: @JasonC I found an online shop with a better photo of that 63216933018 part - https://www.ecstuning.com/b-genuine-bmw-parts/tail-light-side-panel-right/63216933018/. Finding out if the seal is included, if so it should be a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tail lights, usually the seal is part of the assembly. Your best bet is to apply some sealant. Car parts stores will have some, they sell it in tubes.

Comment: This one actually *is* sold separately, #9 [here](http://parts.bmwofsouthatlanta.com/showAssembly.aspx?ukey_assembly=258309&ukey_product=1410563).

Comment: @tlhIngan that's certainly a possible route, but I am going to hold out for a better solution, like the part replacement JasonC has pointed to. My car is almost worn enough to tolerate visible applications of "aftermarket" sealant... but not quite yet.

Comment: Can confirm that this is the way to fix this :) Also, many sealants for sale online.

Answer (score -1):

This piece is called the "Tail Light Side Panel". The part comes with a brand new gasket installed on it.

[image]

The left side is BMW part # **63-21-6-933-017**
The right side is BMW part # **63-21-6-933-018**

This part is for the coupe (Ci) model - if you have a convertible, it's a separate part. The coupe part fits the 323Ci, 325Ci, 328Ci, 330Ci, and M3.

This part is available through BMW, ECS Tuning, or other websites that sell OEM BMW replacement parts.

ECS Tuning product links:

[ECS Tuning Left Panel Link](https://www.ecstuning.com/b-genuine-bmw-parts/tail-light-side-panel-left/63216933017/)

[ECS Tuning Right Panel Link](https://www.ecstuning.com/b-genuine-bmw-parts/tail-light-side-panel-right/63216933018/)

Or if you prefer direct from BMW:

[BMW of Atlanta Left Panel Link](https://parts.bmwofsouthatlanta.com/oem-parts/bmw-cover-63216933017)

[BMW of Atlanta Right Panel Link](https://parts.bmwofsouthatlanta.com/oem-parts/bmw-cover-63216933018)

Comment: Replacing a $200 part for the sake of a $2 seal seems a poor use of money, perhaps the other existing answer is better. And adding sealer is a common solution used on many cars.

Comment: I'm not sure if you clicked on the link... It is a $17.14 panel which is clipped to the side of the tail light. It's not much of a price difference from buying a tube of silicon and allows for a brand new looking OEM finish.